# DustJS: Render partial via a Helper

Tags: javascript, dust.js, dust-helpers

I'm trying to abstract some code and would like to take advantage of dust.helpers to render a parial.

My current setup:

```
{> "includes/components/link" /}
```

My **ideal** setup:

```
{@uiComponent name="link" /}
```

**My helper:**

```
dust.helpers.uiComponent = function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    return dust.render('includes/components/' + name, context, function (err, out) {
        chunk.end(out);
    });
};
```

I have also tried a number of other things and nothing works.

And yes, I tried looking at the documentation. :(

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to handle the partial in a special way or is this simply to abstract the file path away?

Comment: Mainly to abstract the path... currently! But want to have the possibility to manipulate data, if I need to, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dust, helpers return Chunks, so you want to use Chunk methods to return out of your helper rather than `dust.render`.

In this case, you are working with partials, so you want `chunk.partial`:

```
dust.helpers.uiComponent = function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var name = context.resolve(params.name);
  return chunk.partial('includes/components/' + name, context, params);
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much, will give this a go!

Comment: It evaluates a parameter, in case you didn't pass a string but instead passed something like `name="{foo}"`